# As a developer and Stack Overflow user, do you want to prevent Stack Overflow from becoming another ExpertExchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

**The question:** Do you find Stack Overflow useful in your daily development work? Do you want to actively contribute to keep Stack Overflow's content top-notch? If yes, please read on.

**The problem:** The right answer (which just happens to be my answer in this case) for a very important question on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240438/what-are-the-most-used-interfaces-in-c) gets no justice and is being downvoted for appearance rather than content, while a **very** wrong answer is climbing up. The problem is that it will eventually contribute to the 'creation' and 'nurturing' of many bad developers if it stays the way it is (having a very wrong answer as an accepted top answer) as it's nearly as important as the 'What is the base type for all .Net classes?' question.

**What you can do:** If you feel any responsibility towards Stack Overflow for all the hours of work it has saved you and you want to contribute to help create more quality developers rather than bad developers you can visit the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240438/what-are-the-most-used-interfaces-in-c) ([what are the most used interfaces in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240438/what-are-the-most-used-interfaces-in-c)) and:

1. Upvote the question
2. downvote the highest answer
3. Give a few votes to my answer so at least it's not perceived as a
   wrong answer as it's currently below 0 (was above but got downvoted
   by some people)

If you do that, you can go to bed today feeling good that you have contributed in a good meaningful way to a good cause, if not then thanks for looking anyway.

Comment: As the close votes indicate: this is belongs on Meta.

Comment: No.  This belongs nowhere.

Comment: @Slaks: Actually yes, now that I read what the OP is complaining about (the linked question), then yes, I agree. This doesn't belong anywhere.

Comment: Unlike your answer, the accepted answer is correct and sensible, and should not be downvoted.

Comment: If you dont like it, dont answer questions. I was annoyed when people repeat my answer several mins later in their own words that i decided there really is no point and often there are more qualified ppl so i just read and learn instead.

Comment: In your opinion, IList is very important. That's fine, but the whole world does not have to agree 100%. For my part, I understand IList, I've used it in Reflection code, but I believe that INotifyPropertyChanged and IEnumerable<T> are far more important in modern code. Your insistence that you have the One True Answer, and that everyone else is stupid, is not earning you any positive reputation.

Answer (score 19):

**Communications skills.**

Learn 'em, love 'em, live 'em.

In every aspect of your life you *will* be judged by your ability to communicate with people, and that includes not annoying your audience. Your answer is more than a little annoying, and your audience rebelled. Too bad, but you *earned* it.

And it is not like you hadn't been warned. I [told you that style was annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4223398/2509) just the other day. You blew me off.

Comment: This reminds me of another user who would hammer me with a dozen comments to remove my (imperfect) answer to a question, while his - correct - answer was already upvoted, generally recognized as correct, and accepted. For so long that in the end, I decided to leave it in place out of pure spite. The guy even *E-Mailed* me about it. Geez. Excellent answer @dmckee, +1.

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is neither correct nor the right answer for the question.

The non-generic collection interfaces and classes should be viewed as a relic from 2003 and avoided at all costs.

Comment: I disagree with "avoided at all costs"; they can be quite convenient when you're writing things like extension methods or Reflection code.

Comment: @Joe: Extension methods should extend generic interfaces and have generic parameters (like LINQ does).  You're right, though, that the non-generic _interfaces_ are useful for data-binding.

Comment: However, `ArrayList` should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Again, I don't know about "all costs". You could be using third-party code that was written for .NET 1.x. But something is horribly wrong if someone writes new code using ArrayList.

Comment: @Joe: OK, they should be  avoided at _most_ costs.  Is that better?  :-)

Comment: This is off-topic in Meta :)

Answer (score 0):

From where I sit the problem is that you're using `` `backticks` `` for your section headings, which makes no sense.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -3):

I have up voted you because I believe you need a hug and I believe some other people are down vote happy.

Comment: If you want to vote him up, at least vote on an answer which is factually correct.  Not that one.

Comment: Excellent, can I get a few more down votes, I'm trying to get to -10.